# How do I register a domain with special symbols or characters?

Tags: dns, registration, domain-name

[Daring Fireball tweeted](http://twitter.com/daringfireball/status/5629998555):

> ‘We Don’t Lie to Google’: [http://✪df.ws/e4f](http://%E2%9C%AAdf.ws/e4f)

I've been thinking about creating a url shortener and a short url similar to `http://✪df.ws/` would be ideal as no one will ever have to manually type the symbol.

I tried to register a domain with a heart ♥ on a few of the more popular domain name registrars, but upon submitting I was told that the domain name contained invalid characters.

How do I search and register a domain with one of these symbols or characters?

Comment: Voted to close as not programming related.

Comment: This has to be on SF or SU :P

Comment: yeah, sorry... not programming related. Will ask on SF or SU now that I have "discovered" those sister sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [Iwantmyname](http://iwantmyname.com). It's possible for .WS and .LA as far as I know.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned above, an internationalized domain name (IDN) allows the inclusion of language-specific characters.  You can use [this tool](http://xn--domain.net/) to see how such names are mapped into regular ASCII domain names that begin with the special `xn--` followed by regular characters, followed by an encoding to insert special characters within the regular ones.  For example: `xn--nol-kma.com` is the ascii mapping of `noël.com` when the `nol` is the normal part and the `kma` specifies to insert the `ë` between the second and third characters of `nol` to give `noël`.

Comment: General FYI - The link to the IDN tool routes to a wiki that requires a login.

Answer (score 2):

Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name. First of all, many characters are not permitted in IDNS. Secondly, the recent announcement is that registration will open for a limited set of IDNS names in a few months, not now.

Answer (score 1):

You can't register with these characters on all domain-names, such as .com if Im not mistaken. You might want to look into .nu-names which I think allows those characters. It is really not that recommended though.

Comment: It seems to be possible now: `http://www.★.com/` Stack Overflow is trimming it, but if you copy and paste into your address bar, you'll see it.

Answer (score 1):

Well it’s possible to use special characters or symbols into a domain name, there are some stuff that your might know before using. There are some symbols like æ, å, ø, ä or ö which are known as “Punycode” an Internet standard. These characters are not identifiable for ordinary browser as it requires a specific browser package.

However it’s a complicated thing to implement and not beneficial at all. In normal condition, hyphen "-" is the only allowed character which is readable by any browser directly and is typically used to isolate two words in a [domain name](https://domainia.com/register) for example (best-domain.com). Some people remain confused in hyphen and underscore "_" but underscore or any other special character are not permitted. A domain name can be 67 characters long with 4 character domain extension.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.  Those are not valid characters for use in domain names currently.

Comment: Not true. Emoji characters are valid at least in .WS, because they do not implement IDNA2008.

Answer (score 0):

we can get these domains by converting the ascii you want to punycode and all domain registrars suport punycode domains as they are just letters and dashes